# Round-tripping Zarr data from Xarray

Tags: python, amazon-s3, dask, python-xarray, zarr

With `xarray`, I'm using `ds.to_zarr()` to write a dataset to S3 and then `xr.open_zarr()` to see if I get the same dataset back.

My dataset in `xarray` looks like:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                     (nv: 2, reference_time: 11, time: 11, x: 4608, y: 3840)
Coordinates:
  * reference_time              (reference_time) datetime64[ns] 2018-04-01T18:00:00 ...
  * x                           (x) float64 -2.304e+06 -2.303e+06 -2.302e+06 ...
  * y                           (y) float64 -1.92e+06 -1.919e+06 -1.918e+06 ...
  * time                        (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-04-01T19:00:00 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: nv
Data variables:
    time_bounds                 (time, nv) datetime64[ns] dask.array<shape=(11, 2), chunksize=(1, 2)>
    ProjectionCoordinateSystem  (time) |S64 b'' b'' b'' b'' b'' b'' b'' b'' ...
    T2D                         (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<shape=(11, 3840, 4608), chunksize=(1, 3840, 4608)>
```

and I write it to `zarr` using:

```
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
d = s3fs.S3Map(f_zarr, s3=fs)
ds.to_zarr(store=d, mode='w')
```

when I try to read it back in using:

```
ds2 = xr.open_zarr(d)
```

I get back:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-8198db1c8578> in <module>()
----> 1 ds2 = xr.open_zarr(d)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/backends/zarr.py in open_zarr(store, group, synchronizer, auto_chunk, decode_cf, mask_and_scale, decode_times, concat_characters, decode_coords, drop_variables)
    476 
    477         variables = OrderedDict([(k, maybe_chunk(k, v))
--> 478                                  for k, v in ds.variables.items()])
    479         return ds._replace_vars_and_dims(variables)
    480     else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/backends/zarr.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    476 
    477         variables = OrderedDict([(k, maybe_chunk(k, v))
--> 478                                  for k, v in ds.variables.items()])
    479         return ds._replace_vars_and_dims(variables)
    480     else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/backends/zarr.py in maybe_chunk(name, var)
    471                 token2 = tokenize(name, var._data)
    472                 name2 = 'zarr-%s' % token2
--> 473                 return var.chunk(chunks, name=name2, lock=None)
    474             else:
    475                 return var

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/variable.py in chunk(self, chunks, name, lock)
    820             data = indexing.ImplicitToExplicitIndexingAdapter(
    821                 data, indexing.OuterIndexer)
--> 822             data = da.from_array(data, chunks, name=name, lock=lock)
    823 
    824         return type(self)(self.dims, data, self._attrs, self._encoding,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/core.py in from_array(x, chunks, name, lock, asarray, fancy, getitem)
   1977     >>> a = da.from_array(x, chunks=(1000, 1000), lock=True)  # doctest: +SKIP
   1978     """
-> 1979     chunks = normalize_chunks(chunks, x.shape)
   1980     if name in (None, True):
   1981         token = tokenize(x, chunks)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/core.py in normalize_chunks(chunks, shape)
   1907             raise ValueError(
   1908                 "Chunks and shape must be of the same length/dimension. "
-> 1909                 "Got chunks=%s, shape=%s" % (chunks, shape))
   1910 
   1911     if shape is not None:

ValueError: Chunks and shape must be of the same length/dimension. Got chunks=(11, 64), shape=(11,)
```

I am able to read the dataset if I set `auto_chunk=False`:

```
ds2 = xr.open_zarr(d, auto_chunk=False)
ds2
```

results in

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                     (nv: 2, reference_time: 11, time: 11, x: 4608, y: 3840)
Coordinates:
  * reference_time              (reference_time) datetime64[ns] 2018-04-01T18:00:00 ...
  * time                        (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-04-01T19:00:00 ...
  * x                           (x) float64 -2.304e+06 -2.303e+06 -2.302e+06 ...
  * y                           (y) float64 -1.92e+06 -1.919e+06 -1.918e+06 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: nv
Data variables:
    LWDOWN                      (time, y, x) float64 ...
```

But am I not understanding something about chunking and the way `xarray`, `dask` and `zarr` are supposed to work together?

What would I have to do differently to get `auto_chunk=True` to work?

Comment: I would guess that it is variable `ProjectionCoordinateSystem` which is causing the problem, noting the 11-length dimension and the 64-length dtype. You could try explicitly [setting chunks](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.chunk.html) on this variable too, or removing it.

Comment: I think this is probably an untested corner case. Can we move this to github?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @mdurant, the variable `ProjectionCoordinateSystem` with `dtype=S64` was causing the problem.  Since I didn't need this non-standard variable, simply dropping it with

```
ds.drop(['ProjectionCoordinateSystem'])
```

before `ds.to_zarr` solved the problem, allowing `ds.open_zarr()` to work fine with the default `autochunk=True`.

Full notebook here: https://gist.github.com/rsignell-usgs/4a54ea152d4e10a14deff516bf597015

Comment: Did you also try setting the chunks on that variable? I'd be surprised if zarr cannot handle the dtype. Just curious.